# Interacting with secondary window clones the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some code that opens a secondary window like that:

```
var win2 = window.open('second.html', 'secondary', 'width=1024, height=576');
```

Then I need to add elements to the dom, so I initially tried something simple:

```
var canvas = win2.document.createElement('canvas');
win2.document.appendChild(canvas);
```

But whatever I try, the window doesn't change.
I also tried other modifications like changing content of some divs or other.

Where it gets weird is that if I do a `console.log(win2.document);` I can see in the console that my modifications are there. Like it created a clone of the dom that isn't reflected in the actual page.

Is there any way to modify the dom of my second window then?

PS: I'm on the same origin so this souldn't be a same-origin policy problem, although I work on `localhost`, is there an exception for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok never mind so I read about the fact that you should wait for it to load before accessing it.

I added a `setTimeout` of 30ms to test, but it didn't work so I assume that was not the problem.

I actually needed a longer timeout, and then it worked.

So, for a more correct code (instead of a timeout)

```
win2.addEventListener('load', function () {
    callback();
});
```

But the event doesn't seem to be triggered if you reload the parent page. I don't have a solution for this yet.